# WindowObject.print() freeze in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, window-object

I´m trying to print some content from a page.
The page grabs some values from itself and builds a string that eventualy goes into an windowObject.

Problem happens when the user close the print dialog by hitting X in the corner of the print dialog. This will cause the main window (tab) to freeze. It works fine if the user prints the page or hit cancel on the dialog. Also works fine for me in FF.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/atgardmedia/9Pkyv/9/

```
var strHtml = "<html>\n<head></head><body>Content goes here..</body>\n</html>";

WindowObject = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');

WindowObject.document.writeln(strHtml);
WindowObject.print();
WindowObject.close();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try opening and closing the document. Doubt it will make any difference. `WindowObject = window.open(...); WindowObject.document.open(); WindowObject.document.writeln(strHtml); WindowObject.document.close(); WindowObject.print(); WindowObject.close();`

Comment: Tnx, tried your suggestion by adding the .document.close() but still the same result. The calling window in Chrome still freeze up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359627) that will be fixed in Chrome 36 according to the ticket.

Comment: Thanx! I did not see your reply before now..Finally, here comes my 'Thank you' :) (Also the bug does not exists any more)